# Word letter match (wordle game) returning wrong match because of duplicate letters in word

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, wordle-game

I was making a wordle game in TKinter in python, when suddenly I ran into an error with the letter matching function (Return green color if letter in word, and in the correct place, if letter in word but not in correct place, return yellow.) started being weird, and I noticed that if I input a query with duplicate letters, but one letter is in the correct place, it will highlict all of the duplicate letters. ie:
I input:
Boogan

Word is:
Loaren

It highlights:
Bo(green)o(green)gan(green)
It should not highlight the second o because in its place, there is a. Not O.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import string
import os
import asyncio
import random
import aiofiles
import json
import time

# Constants
WINDOW_WIDTH = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
FONT_SIZE = 20
FONT_FAMILY = "Segoe UI"
FRAME_SIZE = 60
STROKE_SIZE = 3
PADY_FRAME = 50
PADX_FRAME = 100
# Integers
guessed = 0
current_guess = 0
is_correct = False
framerow1=None
framerow12 = None
framerow13 = None
framerow14 = None
frame1 = None
frame2 = None
frame3 = None
frame4 = None
frame5 = None
frame12 = None
frame13 = None
frame14 = None
frame22 = None
frame23 = None
frame24 = None
frame32 = None
frame33 = None
frame34 = None
frame42 = None
frame43 = None
frame44 = None
frame52 = None
frame53 = None
frame54 = None

# Variables
word = ""
guessed_letters = []
guessed_words = []
keysin = []
row = 1
frames = []
# Functions
def set_word():
    global word
    wordsList = 'words.json'

    with open(wordsList, 'r') as f:
        words = json.loads(f.read())
        words = words['words']
        while True:
            
            word = random.choice(words)
            if len(word) == 5:
                break
    
def validate_word(word: str) -> bool:
    return  word.isalpha() and len(word) >3

def check_guess(wordGuess: str) -> bool:

    
        
    return wordGuess == word
    

def check_matches(wordG: str) -> list:
    if word == "":
        return False
    matchedLetters = []
    for h in word:
        for g in wordG:
            if g == h:
                matchedLetters.append(g)
    return matchedLetters


def keyed(e):
    if not e.char == '\x08':
        
        if not len(keysin) == 5:
            keysin.append(e.char)
            add_key(e.char)
            
    elif e.char == '\x08':
        if not len(keysin) == 0:
            keysin.remove(keysin[-1])
            add_key(e.char)
    
    
def on_enter(d):
    global current_guess
    f = d
    
     
    if validate_word(f):
        if not check_guess(f):
            current_guess -= 1
            guessed_words.append(f)

            a = check_matches(f)
            
            if len(a)>0:

                guessed_letters.extend(a)
     

 

 
set_word()
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Wordle")
root.geometry(f"{WINDOW_WIDTH}x{WINDOW_HEIGHT}")
root.config(bg="floral white")
root.resizable(False, False)

# Create frame that is as big as the root
framerow1 = tk.Frame(root)
framerow1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx =50)
framerow1.config(bg="floral white")
# Frame one

framebg1 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=63, height=63)
framebg1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=6)

frame1 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=60, height=60)
frame1.grid(row=1, column=1,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame1.config(bg="floral white")

# Frame two
framebg2 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=63, height=63)
framebg2.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=6)

frame2 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=60, height=60)
frame2.grid(row=1, column=2,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame2.config(bg="floral white")

# # Frame three
framebg3 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=63, height=63)
framebg3.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=6)

frame3 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=60, height=60)
frame3.grid(row=1, column=3,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame3.config(bg="floral white")
# # Frame four
framebg4 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=63, height=63)
framebg4.grid(row=1, column=4, pady=10, padx=6)

frame4 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=60, height=60)
frame4.grid(row=1, column=4,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame4.config(bg="floral white")


# # Frame five
framebg5 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=63, height=63)
framebg5.grid(row=1, column=5, pady=10, padx=6)

frame5 = tk.Frame(framerow1, width=60, height=60)
frame5.grid(row=1, column=5,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame5.config(bg="floral white")

framerow12 = tk.Frame(root)
framerow12.grid(row=2, column=1, padx =50)
framerow12.config(bg="floral white")
# Frame one

framebg12 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=63, height=63)
framebg12.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=6)

frame12 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=60, height=60)
frame12.grid(row=1, column=1,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame12.config(bg="floral white")

# Frame two
framebg22 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=63, height=63)
framebg22.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=6)

frame22 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=60, height=60)
frame22.grid(row=1, column=2,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame22.config(bg="floral white")

# # Frame three
framebg32 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=63, height=63)
framebg32.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=6)

frame32 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=60, height=60)
frame32.grid(row=1, column=3,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame32.config(bg="floral white")
# # Frame four
framebg42 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=63, height=63)
framebg42.grid(row=1, column=4, pady=10, padx=6)

frame42 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=60, height=60)
frame42.grid(row=1, column=4,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame42.config(bg="floral white")


# # Frame five
framebg52 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=63, height=63)
framebg52.grid(row=1, column=5, pady=10, padx=6)

frame52 = tk.Frame(framerow12, width=60, height=60)
frame52.grid(row=1, column=5,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame52.config(bg="floral white")

framerow13 = tk.Frame(root)
framerow13.grid(row=3, column=1, padx =50)
framerow13.config(bg="floral white")
# Frame one

framebg13 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=63, height=63)
framebg13.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=6)

frame13 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=60, height=60)
frame13.grid(row=1, column=1,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame13.config(bg="floral white")

# Frame two
framebg23 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=63, height=63)
framebg23.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=6)

frame23 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=60, height=60)
frame23.grid(row=1, column=2,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame23.config(bg="floral white")

# # Frame three
framebg33 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=63, height=63)
framebg33.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=6)

frame33 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=60, height=60)
frame33.grid(row=1, column=3,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame33.config(bg="floral white")
# # Frame four
framebg43 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=63, height=63)
framebg43.grid(row=1, column=4, pady=10, padx=6)

frame43 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=60, height=60)
frame43.grid(row=1, column=4,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame43.config(bg="floral white")


# # Frame five
framebg53 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=63, height=63)
framebg53.grid(row=1, column=5, pady=10, padx=6)

frame53 = tk.Frame(framerow13, width=60, height=60)
frame53.grid(row=1, column=5,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame53.config(bg="floral white")


framerow14 = tk.Frame(root)
framerow14.grid(row=4, column=1, padx =50)
framerow14.config(bg="floral white")
# Frame one

framebg14 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=63, height=63)
framebg14.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=6)

frame14 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=60, height=60)
frame14.grid(row=1, column=1,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame14.config(bg="floral white")

# Frame two
framebg24 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=63, height=63)
framebg24.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=6)

frame24 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=60, height=60)
frame24.grid(row=1, column=2,  pady = 10, padx=6)

frame24.config(bg="floral white")

# # Frame three
framebg34 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=63, height=63)
framebg34.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=6)

frame34 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=60, height=60)
frame34.grid(row=1, column=3,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame34.config(bg="floral white")
# # Frame four
framebg44 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=63, height=63)
framebg44.grid(row=1, column=4, pady=10, padx=6)

frame44 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=60, height=60)
frame44.grid(row=1, column=4,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame44.config(bg="floral white")


# # Frame five
framebg54 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=63, height=63)
framebg54.grid(row=1, column=5, pady=10, padx=6)

frame54 = tk.Frame(framerow14, width=60, height=60)
frame54.grid(row=1, column=5,  pady = 10, padx=6)
frame54.config(bg="floral white")
framerow1s = []
framerow2s = []
framerow3s = []
framerow4s = []
textLost = None
textLost2 = None
frameLost = None
frameWon = None
textWon = None
textWon2 = None

def lost():
    global frameLost
    global textLost
    global textLost2
    frameLost = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=500)
    frameLost.grid(row=4, column=1, padx =50)
    frameLost.config(bg="floral white")
    textLost = tk.Label(frameLost, text="You Lost", font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
    textLost.grid(row=1, column=1)
    textLost.config(bg="floral white")
    textLost2 = tk.Label(frameLost, text="Press Enter to Restart", font=(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE))
    textLost2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    root.bind("<Return>", restart)
    root.unbind("<Key>")

def won():
    global frameWon
    global textWon
    global textWon2
    frameWon = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=500)
    frameWon.grid(row=4, column=1, padx =50)
    frameWon.config(bg="floral white")
    textWon = tk.Label(frameWon, text="You Won", font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
    textWon.grid(row=1, column=1)
    textWon.config(bg="floral white")
    textWon2 = tk.Label(frameWon, text="Press Enter to Restart", font
                         =(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE))
    textWon2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    textWon2.config(bg="floral white")
    root.bind("<Return>", restart)
    root.unbind("<Key>")

def restart(e):
    global row
    global col
    global frameWon
    global textWon
    global textWon2
    global frameLost
    global textLost
    global textLost2
    global keysin
    global framerow1
    global framerow12
    global framerow13
    global framerow14
    row = 1
    col = 0

    if frameWon and textWon and textWon2:
        frameWon.destroy()
        textWon.destroy()
        textWon2.destroy()
    if frameLost and textLost and textLost2:
        frameLost.destroy()
        textLost.destroy()
        textLost2.destroy()
     
    keysin = []
     
    for g in framerow1.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(g, tk.Label):
            g.destroy()
        else:
            if g.cget("bg") == "floral white":
                g.config(width=60, height=60)
            else:
                g.config(width=63, height=63)
    for g in framerow12.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(g, tk.Label):
            g.destroy()
        else:
            if g.cget("bg") == "floral white":
                g.config(width=60, height=60)
            else:
                g.config(width=63, height=63)
    for g in framerow13.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(g, tk.Label):
            g.destroy()
        else:
            if g.cget("bg") == "floral white":
                g.config(width=60, height=60)
            else:
                g.config(width=63, height=63)
    for g in framerow14.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(g, tk.Label):
            g.destroy()
        else:
            if g.cget("bg") == "floral white":
                g.config(width=60, height=60)
            else:
                g.config(width=63, height=63)
    set_word()
    root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: new_line())
    root.bind("<Key>", keyed)
    
    
        
                    

cool = 0
def new_line():
    global row
    global cool
    global word
    global keysin
    global framerow1
    global framerow12
    global framerow1s
    global framerow2s
    global framerow3s
    global framerow4s
    global framerow13
    global framerow14
    frameNow = None
    print(row)
    if row == 1:
        frameNow = framerow1
    elif row == 2:
        frameNow = framerow12
    elif row == 3:
        frameNow = framerow13
    else:
        frameNow = framerow14
    
    if not row == 4:
        if keysin == []:
            return
        row += 1
        on_enter(''.join(keysin))
        
        for i in keysin:
            if i in guessed_letters:
                for h in frameNow.winfo_children():
                    cool += 1
                    animate_flip(h)
                    lb = -1
                    
                    if isinstance(h, tk.Label):
                        h.config(width=3, height=2)
                        animate_flip_frame(h, 'gray16')
                         
                        if h.cget("text")== str(i.upper()):
                            
                             
                            for gg in zip(word, ''.join(keysin)):
                                if gg[0] == gg[1]:
                                    print(''.join(keysin), word)
                                    animate_flip_frame(h, 'dark green')
                                elif gg[0] in gg[1]:
                                    animate_flip_frame(h, 'DarkOrange1')
                                 
                            
                        else:
                            animate_flip_frame(h, 'gray16')
                            
                    
                
        
    elif row == 4:
        if not ''.join(keysin) == word:
            
            lost()
        else:
            
            won()
    keysin = []

def animate_flip_frame(frame,is_gray, i=0):
    
    if i<3:
        frame.config(height=3-i)
        root.after(100, lambda: animate_flip_frame(frame, is_gray,i+1))
    elif i>3:
        frame.config(fg='white')
        frame.config(bg=is_gray)
         
        root.after(100, lambda: animate_flip_frame(frame, is_gray,i+1))
    elif i<6:
        frame.config(fg='white')
        frame.config(bg=is_gray)
         
def animate_flip(frame, i=0):
    if i<3:
        frame.config(height=3-i)
        root.after(300, lambda: animate_flip(frame,i+1))
    elif i>3:
        frame.config(fg='white')
        frame.config(bg=is_gray)
         
        root.after(300, lambda: animate_flip_frame(frame, is_gray,i+1))
    elif i<6:
         
        frame.config(height=2)

        
    
    
def animate_frame(frame, col, i=0):
    frame.configure(bg='floral white')
    if i < 5:
         
         
        
        frame.configure(font=(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE+i))
        root.after(30, animate_frame, frame, col, i+1)
    else:
        frame.configure(font=(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE))
        frame.configure(bg="floral white")
        frame.grid(row=1, column=col, pady=10, padx=6)
def add_key(key):
    col = 0
    cul = 0
    global framerow1
    global framerow12
    global framerow13
    global framerow14
    global frame1
    global frame2
    global frame3
    global frame4
    global frame5
    global frame12
    global frame13
    global frame14
    global frame22
    global frame23
    global frame24
    global frame32
    global frame33
    global frame34
    global frame42
    global frame43
    global frame44
    global frame52
    global frame53
    global frame54
    global keysin
    global frames
    global row
    global keys_guessed
    if row == 1:
        if not key == '\x08':
             
            if key.isalpha():
                if 'x' in key and not key == 'x':
                    return
                
                
                col = 0
                cus = 0
                frame = False
                 
                if key in keysin and  key == keysin[-1] and not len(keysin) == 6:
                    
                    col = 0
                    for gh in keysin:
                         
                        col += 1
                        if key == gh and keysin.index(gh) == len(keysin)-1:
                            break
                   
                     
                    lbl2 = tk.Label(framerow1, text=(str(key)).upper(), font=(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE+5))
                    
                    
                    lbl2.grid(row=1, column=col, pady=5, padx=3)
                    
                    animate_frame(lbl2, col)
                     
                    
                     
                    
                        
        else:
            
             
            labls = []
            
            for i in framerow1.winfo_children():
                if isinstance(i,tk.Label):
                    labls.append(i)
            if len(labls) > 0:
                 
                
                labls[-1].destroy()
    elif row == 2:
        if not key == '\x08':
             
            if key.isalpha():
                if 'x' in key and not key == 'x':
                    return


                col = 0
                cus = 0
                frame = False
                print(len(keysin))
                if key in keysin and  key == keysin[-1] and not len(keysin) == 6:

                    col = 0
                    for gh in keysin:

                        col += 1
                        if key == gh and keysin.index(gh) == len(keysin)-1:
                            break
                    print(col)

                    lbl2 = tk.Label(framerow12, text=(str(key)).upper(), font=(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE))
                     
                    lbl2.grid(row=1, column=col, pady=10, padx=6)

                    animate_frame(lbl2, col)


                    print(key)


        else:

            print(key)
            labls = []

            for i in framerow12.winfo_children():
                if isinstance(i,tk.Label):
                    labls.append(i)
            if len(labls) > 0:


                labls[-1].destroy()
    elif row ==3:
        if not key == '\x08':
            print(key)
            if key.isalpha():
                if 'x' in key and not key == 'x':
                    return


                col = 0
                cus = 0
                frame = False
                print(len(keysin))
                if key in keysin and  key == keysin[-1] and not len(keysin) == 6:

                    col = 0
                    for gh in keysin:

                        col += 1
                        if key == gh and keysin.index(gh) == len(keysin)-1:
                            break
                    print(col)
                    
                    lbl2 = tk.Label(framerow13, text=(str(key)).upper(), font=(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE))
                     
                    lbl2.grid(row=1, column=col, pady=10, padx=6)

                    animate_frame(lbl2, col)


                    print(key)


        else:

            print(key)
            labls = []

            for i in framerow13.winfo_children():
                if isinstance(i,tk.Label):
                    labls.append(i)
            if len(labls) > 0:


                labls[-1].destroy()

    elif row == 4:
        if not key == '\x08':
            print(key)
            if key.isalpha():
                if 'x' in key and not key == 'x':
                    return


                col = 0
                cus = 0
                frame = False
                print(len(keysin))
                if key in keysin and  key == keysin[-1] and not len(keysin) == 6:

                    col = 0
                    for gh in keysin:

                        col += 1
                        if key == gh and keysin.index(gh) == len(keysin)-1:
                            break
                    print(col)

                    lbl2 = tk.Label(framerow14, text=(str(key)).upper(), font=(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE))
                     
                    lbl2.grid(row=1, column=col, pady=10, padx=6)

                    animate_frame(lbl2, col)


                    print(key)


        else:

            print(key)
            labls = []

            for i in framerow14.winfo_children():
                if isinstance(i,tk.Label):
                    labls.append(i)
            if len(labls) > 0:


                labls[-1].destroy()


# Guess textbox

 
 
guessed_letters = []
guessed_words = []
current_guess = 10

is_correct = False


root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: new_line())
root.bind("<Key>", keyed)
root.mainloop()
```

Also, it would be appreciated if someone could tell me how to make the flip animations more like wordle. Thanks!

I tried the zipping function, and indexing it in both the word and the keys entered